# What happens to the websocket when a mobile device crashes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, browser

I would like to know what happens to the websocket when a mobile device is blocked and I also wanted to know if it is possible to detect from the browser if a mobile device was blocked?

Comment: What do you mean when you use the term "blocked"?

Comment: I mean that the user presses the power button 1 only time

Comment: So you mean when the phone is put in standby mode? Because unless the websocket is running as part of a true app, as part of a webview or browser this isn't related to the phone so much as "the browser" (including web views)

Comment: yes, the websocket runs as part of an application

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.